# Android kernel blackscreen on bootanimation

Tags: android, linux, kernel

I'm building a kernel (3.10.108) for the OnePlus 2 and it compiles successfully. The thing is when I boot it goes through 1+ logo then enters bootanimation the after first part of bootanimation, the phone just show a black screen.

Anyone can tell me what seems to be the problem here? what file, module, etc

Thanks!

The kernel I'm building is a rebase of a kernel that already boots. So I could compare pstore logs and they are really similar.

New thing is that I now see a watchdog bite at the end of the log so it now tells that it crashes.

Can't get any logcat, but here's pstore message
Console-ramoops:
https://del.dog/ehikujelof.coffeescript
Pmsg-ramoops:
https://del.dog/ehikujelof.rb

Comment: Hi there. Is this programming related?

Comment: kernel development so yea there is code behind it

Comment: please share the code that has issue.

Comment: thats the thing I dont know where to look at. I thought log would tell me where to.Since there are a whole bunch of files